# Roblox Lua - Color3 expected, got string

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local colorTable = {
    ('11, 13, 48'), 
    ('35, 48, 48'), 
    ('6, 47, 6'),
    ('91, 5, 7')
}

local value = math.random(1,#colorTable) 
local picked_value = colorTable[value] 
script.Parent.Background.BackgroundColor3 = picked_value
```

My error code was `Color3 expected, got string`, is there anything I can fix this? My goal was simple, randomizing a specific color rgb to a frame backrgound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Color3` object can be created by `Color3.fromRGB`.

```
local colorTable = {
    Color3.fromRGB(11, 13, 48), 
    ...
}
```